# quadratic ring mod prime ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I would like to ask if the following statement is true.

Consider a quadratic integer ring $R$ that is a Euclidean domain and $p$ a prime element of $R.$ Then $R/(p)$ is a field and is isomorphic to a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ where $q=|N(p)|$ (the absolute value of the norm of the element $p$).

If this is true, in what book can I find a proof of it? Thank you so much!

Comment: In books on abstract algebra, or in books on algebraic number theory and on this site, too.

Comment: @DietrichBurde can I ask for a specific book? Thanks!